# gvisMotionChart is not working in R markdown file

Tags: r, markdown, googlevis

I need to embed gvisMotionChart into an R markdown file and find an example [interactive](http://slidify.github.io/interactive/) which is really helpful. However when it comes to the googlevis plotting I keep getting this error when I press the "run code" button:

```
connection to openCPU failed:
error
undefined
NetworkError: A network error occurred
```

Can anybody figure out the solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The googleVis package creates the javascript that has to be embedded into an HTML document in order for the interactive plot to run on a webpage. You won't be able to get it to work in the console or in Rstudio for that reason. The only way to know for sure if it's working is to  knit it to HTML, and then publish it to Rpubs (or anywhere else online). Once it is online it will work. Depending on your browser settings, you might be able to get it to work by opening the HTML locally, but the browser often blocks the embedded plot when opened locally.

Without seeing your actual code, I can't provide you with anything more specific than that.

EDIT: I thought I would add that several months ago I made a markdown file detailing interactive plots in R for a class. You can find it here: http://rpubs.com/crmhaske/uwloo670_Interactive_Plots

If you scroll down to the very end you'll see the example I did using gvisMotionChart. You have to make sure the place where you print the graph is in it's own chunk, and that results is asis:

````
```{r results='asis'}
print(p,'chart')
```
````